# How to get Plyr current instance when initialized for many videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, plyr, plyr.js

I'm using **[Plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr)** in my webpage to play Youtube embeds in that. In my page I've about 10 videos/embeds, & my current setup like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID1"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID2"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID3"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID4"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID5"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID6"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID7"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID8"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID9"></div>
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID10"></div>
```

**JS**

```
const players = Plyr.setup('.plyr', options);
```

now If I play video #3 on the page how can I get that instance so that I can control the player & listen to that instances events so that I can do something else with those.

The documentation only talks about single instance when instantiating only one player

```
const player = new Plyr('#player', options);
```

but I instantiated multiple at once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you should do is to add your variable to `data-plyr-config` like this

```
<div class="plyr" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="videoID10" data-plyr-config='{ "the_id": "YOUR ID" }'></div>
```

then in your Js code you can get the variable

```
const plyr = Plyr.setup('. plyr', config);
    plyr.forEach(function (instance) {
        instance.on('playing', function () {
            console.log(instance.config.the_id);
        });
    });
```

- where 'the_id' is the key that you just created
- Note: The key name can be anything